# Reusing ProviderUserKey in MVC without DB fetching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, asp.net-membership

So I'm trying to reuse `Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey` to get the UserID of the currently logged in user without re-fetchingit on every call.

Everything I've read so far says use a Profile Value, however if the profiles are stored on the SQL server using `SQLProfileProvider` does that offer any advantages over the db round trip?

Is there a way to declare a object in MVC that is fetched once (for each HTTP Post, I realise this couldn't be re-used over multiple postbacks).

- Session is using a SQL Provider
- Profile is using a SQL Provider
- Membership is using a SQL Provider

The application is running on a web farm so I need to utilize the SQL servers, but would like to cache on a per-machine basis on each request rather than doing 100 round trips to get the UserID each time its needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.Identity.Name` is what you are looking for. If you are using [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) this simply comes from the authentication cookie that an authenticated client sends automatically with each request. Gives you the currently authenticated username. No Membership (a.k.a DB) access.

If you want to store some additional info about the user you could use the `user data` section of the forms authentication ticket and a custom Authorize attribute to retrieve a custom `IPrincipal` on each request from the cookie.

Comment: I'm Afraid User.Identity.Name won't work, I'm looking to get the primary key (ProviderUserKey) not the username so that I can insert into other tables where there is a FK to the user table.

Comment: Then you will have to store it as part of the `user data` section of the forms authentication cookie to avoid hitting the db at each request as I have already explained in my answer. Was there something unclear about my answer that deserved a downvote? Was there something you didn't understand? I'd be happy to elaborate if this was the case. I just thought that was obvious to everyone. Apparently I was wrong and there were people that didn't understand.

Comment: I was actually referring to the person that downvoted. It would have been nice if he left a comment explaining his motivation behind this downvote.